# WLAN network interface name in JAVA

Tags: java, networking, netsh, wifi

I am working on a JAVA project to list wlan interfaces names.

I am using this unix command to display all wlan interfaces:

```
> netsh wlan show interface
Name: Wi-Fi
Description: ...
...

Name: Wi-Fi 2
Description: ...
...
```

I have another JAVA code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> a = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (a.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = a.nextElement();
            if (ni.isUp()) {
                System.out.println(ni.getDisplayName());
            }
}
```

It returns wlan interfaces "real" names:

```
 wlan0
 wlan1
```

Is there any way to match network interfaces name returned by JAVA and names returned by netsh command:

wlan0 equivalent name is: Wi-Fi

wlan1 equivalent name is: Wi-Fi 2

Comment: Do you also capture the output of the netsh wlan show interface? Otherwise as you say wlan0 is equivlanet to Wi-Fi and so on, so the conversion seems to be consistent.

Comment: Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi2 names ... differs from one computer to another

Comment: Then match by another attribute like the MAC address.